# Google Analytics Reporting API v4 - 1MM row limit

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How to Increase Data limit for Analytics 360 using resource based quota: 100M sessions

As per the documentation, I'm setting the **useResourceQuotas flag to True** to enable this feature, which would allow up to 100MM sessions per request:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/resource-based-quota

After running a test query for a single date in the postman I do see that the sampling is removed (samplesReadCounts is absent in the response). However, I'm still getting only 1MM total rows in the response, even though I know for a fact there are more than 1MM rows.

Endpoint: analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet

Some things to note:
I am requesting data on behalf of client and accessing data via accesstoken (Client is having Google Analytics 360 account)

Comment: facing the same issue